# SAPUI5 sap.m.ListBase.getItems() returns previous contents?

Tags: list, sapui5

My App does the following things:

1. Refreshes the model
2. Applies filters
3. Gets the items of a table using the `.getItems()`
4. Loops at the items and applies CSS

Upon testing CSS, noticed that something wasn't right, correct CSS attributes were applies on the 2nd time when I pressing the button with the same filters. Started debugging and as soon as I reached the loop, I found out that the `.getItems()` seems to return the previous contents of the table.

Noticed also while having the debugger open and proceeding step by step that right before the actual contents appear on the screen, a previous list corresponding to the previous data and with correct CSS attributes flashing on the screen for a moment. Thought that the method is asynchronous and I have to implement the loop within the success function but when I visited the documentation [List getItems()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/getItems) I noticed that the method accepts no such parameters.

In case the above are correct and I'm not missing anything, how can I retrieve the actual contents of the table?

Code (4 lines actually, remaining part is the loop) embedded below, thanks in advance.

```
oView.getModel("Report").refresh(true, true);
this.byId("statusReportTable").getBinding("items").filter(oTableSearchState);
this.getModel("Global").setProperty("/statusTableVisible", true);
this.oStsTable = this.getView().byId("statusReportTable");
var aItems = this.oStsTable.getItems();
if (aItems && aItems.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < aItems.length; i++) {
    if (i === aItems.length - 1) {
      aItems[i].addStyleClass("pinkBackground");
    } else {
      var even = i % 2;
      if (even !== 0 && i < aItems.length) {
        aItems[i].addStyleClass("cyanBackground");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be more patient before posting. Found the answer, it's just a matter of attaching an `updateFinished` event on the table and putting the `getItems()` in there.

Comment: Just a note - the `updateFinished` event gets fired for multiple reasons like sorting, filtering, refreshing, or if any of the values of the list items are changed -- so you may want to add something like `if oEvent.getParameter("reason") === "Refresh"` to avoid running your code more than you intended to

Comment: @Kyle : Thank you (didn't know that), however I think I've got it covered by using attachEventOnce inside the button code.